# image resize to fit screen jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

It is possible from an image that is in any position of the screen (being resized), clicking the image to enlarge the entire screen of the mobile device using jquery mobile?

Thank you

Comment: You are asking about code to enlarge a given image to the full size of the browser?  Even if it skews the original scale?

Comment: Yes, the images have a resolution very large

Comment: he meant skew, as in the dimensions does not scale perfectly to the screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too familiar with JQuery-mobile however you could use an onClick jquery event to change the width of the image to 100% and height to auto (or vice versa), change the position to absolute, and the z-index to 500, that should give you what you want.